# DefaultTableModel java + sql

Tags: java, sqlite, vector, datatable, defaulttablemodel

I wanted to implement a Table in my GUI to show the patientlist of my database. It does not show me anything. Someone got a idea why it does not work? I am nearly sure that this code should work.I hope someone can help me.

```
private void initTable() throws SQLException {

    Vector columnNames = new Vector();
    Vector rowData = new Vector();

    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
    table.setModel(tableModel);
    table.setBounds(10,410,50,20);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    conn = Connector.connection();

    PreparedStatement stm;
    String query = "Select * from patient;";
    stm = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    try {
        rs = stm.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int i = 0;
    while(rs.next()){
        rs.getString(i);
        rowData.add(i,rs);
        i++;
    }



    columnNames.add("PatientID");
    columnNames.add("Surname");
    columnNames.add("Lastname");
    columnNames.add("Birthdate");
    columnNames.add("Adress");
    columnNames.add("Height");
    columnNames.add("Weight");
    columnNames.add("Gender");
    columnNames.add("Emergencycontact");
    columnNames.add("Emergencynumber");
    columnNames.add("roomNr");


    conn.close();
}
```

Regards Samir

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it doesn't show anything", is it literal? Without making assumptions, I would recommend checking below points:

1. When you use Swing, make sure your have below codes in your JFrame:

   ```
   frame.setContentPane(container);
   frame.pack();
   frame.setVisible(true);
   ```
2. You have created a DefaultTableModel after the columnNames vector is assigned with data, try moving the assignment forward.
3. You have updated the table data vector after the DefaultTableModel is created. Try

   ```
   tableModel.fireTableChanged();
   ```